# Setting a variable counter to start at zero but doesn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, logical-operators

I am reposting this question with an updated code.

When I run this code to calculate simple interest gained over the years (in a nice table form), my table column for years starts with 5. Also, the total is being calculated with the year starting from 5. Just to clarify, I am using 5 as an example for the user input when asked for the totYear.

```
    #Declare the necessary variables.
princ = 0
interest = 0.0
totYear = 0
year = 1

#Get the amont of principal invested.
print("Enter the principal amount.")
princ = int(input())

#Get the interest rate being applied.
print("Enter the interest rate.")
interest = float(input())

#Get the total amount of years principal is invested.
print ("Enter the total number of years you're investing this amonut.")
totYear = int(input())

print("Year      Interest")
for year in range(totYear):
    total=totYear*interest*princ
    print (totYear,"      $",total)
    totYear+=1

if total<100:
    print("That is not too much interest!")
else:
    print("This interest really adds up!")
```

This is output screen:

```
Enter the principal amount.
10
Enter the interest rate.
5
Enter the total number of years you're investing this amonut.
5
Year      Interest
5       $ 250.0
6       $ 300.0
7       $ 350.0
8       $ 400.0
9       $ 450.0
This interest really adds up!
```

THANK YOU FOR ANY HELP!

Comment: You want to print `year` since that is the variable that will go through the range. I don't think you need to increment `totYear`

Comment: try printing `year` instead of `totYear`

Answer (score 0):

Is this the output you want?

```
Enter the principal amount.
10
Enter the interest rate.
5
Enter the total number of years you're investing this amonut.
5
Year      Interest
0       $ 250.0
1       $ 300.0
2       $ 350.0
3       $ 400.0
4       $ 450.0
This interest really adds up!
```

If so then you need to replace `print (totYear,"      $",total)` with this:

`print (year,"      $",total)`

Also, you don't need to initialize `year` as it is initialized in the for.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change your totYear in the loop to year as year is the counter

```
for year in range(totYear):
    total=year*interest*princ
    print (year,"      $",total)
    #totYear+=1 //delete this line
```

Then delete the last incrementation

Comment: Thanks, that helped my issue with it calculating the same year (totYear) for every iteration. Now it does it right by taking each year into the calculation. How do I get the output to include up to and including the totYear? I want to show what interest they accrued on their final year but it cuts off one before.

Comment: then change the for loop to for year in range(totYear+1):  If it helps plz upvote and accept answer thanks.

Comment: The fix I used was add a "+1" to the the user input when declaring the totYear variable. Since the range function only reads from starting value up to but not including the ending value.

Comment: That was not so favorable as if you are going to use that totYear variable elsewhere it might give you error, +1 in the  loop range is a better solution.

Comment: Please kindly click the upward arrow and the tick to the left of the answer to appreciate their time and effort if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the loop I gave you in the previous question, with the print statement updated to include the year.  I've added the "+1" adjustment you already figured out.  Format as you wish.

```
princ = 10000
interest = 0.10
totYears = 5

for year in range(1, totYears+1):
    total = year * interest * princ
    print (year, total)
```

Output:

```
1 1000.0
2 2000.0
3 3000.0
4 4000.0
5 5000.0
```